# Strange error while accessing Wp-admin?

Tags: wordpress

We have development server at office. Where we have installed couples of websites. 
When I am trying to access from all office computers.

1) http://dev.example.com/website1/wp-admin

2) http://dev.example.com/website2/wp-admin

Both are redirecting to cgi-sys/denied.shtml.
But when I am trying to access from other networks it works perfectly. 
What could be the issue? anybody have any ideas?

Comment: have you checked `.htaccess` ?

Comment: yes. if this is the issue it should effect on one website only

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all plugins first, especially security plugins like WordFence. Once you disable the plugins, retry the sites. If you see the same result, it is probably something related to your network configuration - router or firewall restriction.